# Regex for Rest Design

Tags: javascript, java

I want to implement a validation for java back end side.In java, I want that all characters are allowed except / # + % ?(5 characters).I think these characters may damage my rest structure.

I implement this pattern `"^[^#%/+?]+$"`.But It is not working.Do you have any idea about pattern.

```
    if(data.getName.matches("^[^#%/+?]+$""){
 return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert("data","error","new data is not proper")).body(null)
```

}

It return created status when i send /pen or pencil% like that.

Comment: When you say it's not working, what exactly isn't working? Is your code not picking up the pattern at all? Is it just allowing one of those characters?

Comment: Define "it's not working", precisely. Post a complete minimal example, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: I use Matches method in java.If It matches ,code returns error message.

Comment: If user enters these characters,I want to send an error message.These function is ready.But pattern is not working.

Comment: I updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match any of those characters, you could do something like:

```
if (s.matches(".*[#%\\/+?].*"))
```

See online demo [here](https://ideone.com/wdNa2v)

Comment: thank you ver much.Why do you use \\?.Your code is working

Comment: It should work as is. You can change to `".*[#%/+?].*"` but that will do the same thing.

Comment: Ok.I updated the pattern.It is woking like that    ".*[#%\\/+? ].*".Thank you very much